jetpack compose horizontal constaints don't see to work
i want to position a box in the right of the container
here is the code i have:
Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.Cyan)

            ){
                ConstraintLayout {
                    val (leftt,middle,rightt) = createRefs()

                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
                            .width(50.dp)
                            .background(Color.Yellow)
                            .constrainAs(rightt){
                                end.linkTo(parent.end)
                            }
                    ){
                        Text("s99")
                    }

i tried using
absoluteRight

but it didn't work

Text("Price")
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(50.dp)
            .background(Color.Yellow)
    ) {
        Text("s99")
    } do you really need constaint layout??


I'm not sure but as per my understanding, the view you are looking for looks like this?

If yes, Here is the code snippet. I just modified your code.
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Cyan)
            .wrapContentSize(Alignment.TopEnd)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .width(50.dp)
                .background(Color.Yellow)
        ) {
            Text("s99")
        }
    }


I hope this helps you well.

Your code doesn't work because you don't provide "width" to the layout constraint. Because you don't give a "width" to the ConstraintLayout, the ConstraintLayout will have a length that matches the length of its child.
Add fillMaxWidth modifier to constraint layout.
@Preview(showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun Test() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Cyan)

    ) {
        ConstraintLayout(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            val (leftt, middle, rightt) = createRefs()

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
                    .width(50.dp)
                    .background(Color.Yellow)
                    .constrainAs(rightt) {
                        end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    }
            ) {
                Text("s99")
            }
        }
    }
}


